# Different log files for different log levels in logback

Tags: java, logback

I am trying to insert log information into files based on Log level using below  Logback configuration . I would like to insert log information to each different file (like info into info file, debug into debug file..) to achieve this i am using the below configuration file and with this i can insert info information into info file successfully. But i am not able to insert debug information into debug file.Pls help me on this how to over come. Thanks.

```
<property name="DEV_HOME" value="d:/log" />

<appender name="FILE-INSERT-DEBUG"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>     

    <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip
                    </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<appender name="FILE-INSERT-INFO"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>

    </filter>     

    <file>${DEV_HOME}/INFO.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/INFO.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip
                    </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<logger name="com.code" level="Debug"
    additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-INSERT-DEBUG" />
</logger> 

    <logger name="com.code" level="Info"
    additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-INSERT-INFO" />
</logger>  



    <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-INSERT-DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-INSERT-INFO" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Why debug logs are not getting printed?

> A log request of level p issued to a logger having an effective level
>   q, is enabled if p >= q.

It assumes that levels are ordered as follows: TRACE < DEBUG < INFO <  WARN < ERROR.

Set the root logger level as "DEBUG", which is it's default value.

2) Change your logback configuration as below,:-

```
<appender name="FILE-INSERT-DEBUG"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>     

    <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip
                    </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<appender name="FILE-INSERT-INFO"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
      <level>INFO</level>
      <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
    </filter> 
     <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
      <level>DEBUG</level>
      <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
    </filter>     
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/INFO.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/INFO.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip
                    </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>


    <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-INSERT-DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-INSERT-INFO" />
</root>
```

You can easily extend the above configuration for other levels.

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks Amit.